# How to format timestamp

Tags: php, pdo, timestamp

Help me, i wanna put the timestone to this format Hour:minutes:secondes

```
$services = $pdo ->prepare("SELECT * FROM `servicos` WHERE `DE` = :u");
$services->bindValue(":u", "1");
$services->execute();
echo $numServico = $services->rowCount(); // Contagem de serviços
$l = $services->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
//$json = json_encode($l);
echo '{"data":[';
//echo $json;


foreach ($l as $listar) {



    $inicioHora = new DateTime("listar->REGISTRO");
    $inicioHora = $inicioHora->format('H:i:s');



}
```

But i receive this 
     Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message   'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (listar->REGISTRO) at position 0 (l): The timezone could not be found in the database'  on line 26

Comment: `"listar->REGISTRO"` is not the same as `$listar->REGISTRO` is it?

Answer (score 2):

if the field $listar->REGISTRO is a timestamp, then you only need to use the date() function http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
$time = date('H:i:s', $listar->REGISTRO);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
$inicioHora = new DateTime("listar->REGISTRO");
$inicioHora = $inicioHora->format('H:i:s');
```

With this:

```
$inicioHora = date('H:i:s', strtotime($listar->REGISTRO));
```